# Remove SQL Comments from Stored Procedure - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We would like to remove developer comments from stored procedures for some specific reason.

Is there any mechanism available within SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Better would be to create something that does not allows a stored procedure to compile if there are no comments in it. Comments are usefull

Comment: We are going to keep original SP for developer/future reference but for some reason we need a copy without comments.

Comment: "within sql server" - no.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to script alter statements based on meta data and strip the comments in the process.

As a starting point take a look at sys.sql_modules

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id) AS [SchemaName],
       OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id) AS [ObjectName], o.type, m.definition
FROM   sys.sql_modules m 
inner join sys.all_objects o  on o.object_id = m.object_id 
where o.is_ms_shipped = 0 
order by OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id) ;
```

But I don't know why you don't just manually script the sp's to a text file and strip it before running.

Comment: To get it to work in a  practical (well..) setup you probably need to manage the SPs as source code in e.g. TFS and make a deployment script that deploy them without the comments. In the dev env you would have the comments left of course.